# Como puedo leer el valor de un elemento de un archivo xml y devolver el contenido?

Tags: c#, xml, mvc

Tengo una aplicacion la cual tiene un archivo xml. Este archivo xml esta serializado con el contenido en el cual viene de una variable de una pagina web.

Lo que necesito hacer ahora es obtener el valor de cada uno de los elementos de este archivo xml y compararlos en un if.

El objetivo es que si el nombre de usuario y contraseña son los mismos a los que estan en el archivo xml y asi poder validar al usuario.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Gracias

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer esto.. me parece que esta pregunta esta basada en opiones.. puedes descerializarlo a una clase, leerlo manualmente como un XML, o hasta leerlo como un archivo de texto..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te paso un ejemplo:

```
public static Usuario ObtenerUsuario(string nombreUsuario, string clave)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\usuarios.xml"));
        IEnumerable<XElement> results = from m in root.Elements("Usuario")
                                        where (String)m.Attribute("usuario") == nombreUsuario
                                        select m;

        Usuario objUsuario = null;

        if (results.Count() > 0)
        {
            objUsuario = new Usuario();
            XElement usuario = results.ToList()[0];
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Usuario));
            objUsuario = (Usuario)serializer.Deserialize(usuario.CreateReader());
        }

        return objUsuario;
    }
```

Y tu objeto Usuario seria:

```
public class Usuario
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String usuario { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public String clave { get; set; }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si amigo, use tu ejemplo y me resulto de buena forma. Muchas gracias.